# What is the current best practice for testing a DoFn that use MapState

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm writing a piece of dataflow transform that uses `org.apache.beam.sdk.state.MapState` to implement caching functionality. However upon introducing `MapState`, the unit test starts to dysfunction. The exception says: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Parameter StateParameter{referent=StateDeclaration{id=cache, field=private final org.apache.beam.sdk.state.StateSpec xxxxFn.cache, stateType=org.apache.beam.sdk.state.MapState<java.lang.String, object>}} not supported by DoFnTester`

So if `DoFnTester` is no longer an option, what is the current best practice for testing a DoFn that use MapState?

P.S. I'm currently on Beam 2.0.0, and I can't upgrade to 2.2.0 because https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3693

Here is the complete Trace:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Parameter StateParameter{referent=StateDeclaration{id=cache, field=private final org.apache.beam.sdk.state.StateSpec xxxxFn.cache, stateType=org.apache.beam.sdk.state.MapState<java.lang.String, object>}} not supported by DoFnTester
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnTester$5.dispatchDefault(DoFnTester.java:725)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnTester$5.dispatchDefault(DoFnTester.java:710)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.reflect.DoFnSignature$Parameter$Cases$WithDefault.dispatch(DoFnSignature.java:255)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.reflect.DoFnSignature$Parameter.match(DoFnSignature.java:193)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnTester.<init>(DoFnTester.java:709)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnTester.of(DoFnTester.java:92)
    at xxxxFnTest.testNormalRun(GetPredictionsFnTest.java:50)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java `DirectRunner` is the best way to test your `DoFn`, whatever features it uses.

Using `DoFnTester` will enable you to gain false confidence by testing scenarios that are not feasible while missing scenarios that can really happen. For this reason, and bugs / lack of maintenance, `DoFnTester` is now deprecated and you should try to move off of it.

To have control over watermarks, the processing clock, and element bundling, you can use `TestStream` as described on the [Beam blog](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2016/10/20/test-stream.html).

Comment: According to [link](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/pipelines/test-your-pipeline/), `DirectRunner` is for End-to-end testing, and `DoFnTester` is for testing individual `DoFn`. Since `DoFnTester` is deprecated, does that mean we need to build a separate `TestPipeline` for every DoFn, as it was suggested in the "Testing a Pipeline End-to-End" section of the article?

Comment: Yes, you should just build a little test pipeline that feeds some sample data through a `ParDo` transform.